# Using django models in a script

Tags: python, django

I have a `xml` parser that will store that data into a `MySQL` database, as part of a django app. The parser is intended to run daily, capturing some tests outputs:

```
`dbsync.py`:

   1 #!/usr/bin/env python
   2 import os
   3 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'autotester.settings'
   4 
   5 import xml_parser
   6 from models import *
```

The `Django` project is called `autotester` and the `app` is called `autoreporter`.
When I execute

```
python dbsync.py
```

I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoreporter/dbsync.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import *
  File "/root/autotester/autoreporter/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'autotester.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named autotester.settings
```

How can I have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set, so I can execute the `dbsync.py` script properly?

Comment: Where is the script located in regards to your project structure?

Comment: One problem is probably you do not have `autotester.settings` in the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Why not make the script a Django management command? That would let the framework take care of all of this.

Comment: @Joe  this sounds like a great idea is there a way you can post a answer as an example ?

Comment: @cmidi I haven't written much of the script ... that's all the script is actually

Answer (score 1):

Two issues

1. You need to import models from your app, so provided that your Django project is in the `PYTHONPATH` you can simply import the app models by:

`from autoreporter.models import *`

or do a relative import, if dbsync.py(looks from your traceback) is in the app directory.

```
from .models import *
```

2. Add Django project to `PYTHONPATH`. You need to have the Django project in the `PYTHONPATH` to it be accessed from your dbsync.py(provided it is in your django app directory), quick easy fix for this would be to do the following in your code to dbsync.py.

   ```
   import sys
   import os
   ##get project directory
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   ##get project parent directory and add to python path using sys.path.append
   SYS_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
   if SYS_PATH not in sys.path:
       sys.path.append(SYS_PATH)
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'autotester.settings'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I run a few scripts using the ORM without the rest of Django. I wouldn't set the environment in the script.

Since Django 1.7 you need to import your models, and run django setup.

I would set the environment as you do for the main Django application. Then at the start of your script add these lines. Those should set up the Django environment so it can access your models the same way a standard Django app will.

```
import django
django.setup()

import xml_parser
from .models import *
```

Comment: would this work if the script is not present in the app directory ?
I see you are doing a relative import of the model using `.model` ?

Comment: You would have to run it with the working directory in the same place as manage.py, so that the settings file gets imported correctly. But the script can be anywhere.